# Get Selected Row Value In Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I'm able to get the selected row in kendo grid, But I'm unable to get the specific selected row data in detail grid.

[image]

One thing that I expect is just get the Ticket_ID field string **"5d484b061bf03"**.

I've tried to make my code just like this:

```
function onChange(arg) {
       var selected = $.map(this.select(), function(item) {
            return $(item).text();
       });
       myWindow.data("kendoWindow").open();
       undo.fadeOut();
       console.log(selected.TICKET_ID);
}
```

But just getting "**undefined**".

Any well thought to advise will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Add more of your grid's code. Its hard to guess the issue with so little piece of code. I'm not sure what is `onChange`, or `this.select()`. You say *detail grid* but I can see a detail grid in the screen shot. Also the object printed in the console is very wierd. It seems that all columns values are concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [`$.map`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) returns an array constructed of return values, and you are returning strings.

See Telerik example in API reference for [kendo.ui.Grid change](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/change) to see more about getting the data items used to construct the selected grid rows.  The data items will have a field corresponding to the ticket_id value.  The name of the field is case-sensitive.

> ```
> change: function(e) {
>   var selectedRows = this.select();
>   var selectedDataItems = [];
>   for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
>     var dataItem = this.dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
>
>     console.log (dataItem);
>
>     selectedDataItems.push(dataItem);
>   }
>   // selectedDataItems contains all selected data items
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can get and persist selected row on a specific page after edit or paging  in change and databound events like this:

```
Grid_OnRowSelect = function (e) {                
    this.currentPageNum = grid.dataSource.page();
    //Save index of selected row      
    this.selectedIndex = grid.select().index();       
}

.Events(e => e.DataBound(
    @<text>
        function(e)
        {
            //جهت نمایش صحیح پیجینگ
            var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.pager.resize();          

            //در صورت تغییر صفحه، سطر را انتخاب نکند
            if(this.currentPageNum == grid.dataSource.page())
            {
                //انتخاب مجدد سطر انتخاب شده قبل از ویرایش
                var row = grid.table.find("tr:eq(" + this.selectedIndex + ")");
                grid.select(row);
            }
        }
    </text>)
 )
```